# How do I copy files on build of one project to the include/library directories of a second project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dll, build

I have a MSVC2013 Solution with 2 projects, one for a `DLL`Library and one for an executable to test the library.
My folder structure is:

```
SolutionDir
|-- DLL
|   `-- src
|-- Executable
|   `-- src
|-- .libs
|   |-- DLL
|   |   |-- include
|   |   |-- bin
|   |   `-- lib
|   `-- (others)
`-- .build
    |-- Executable
    |   |-- Debug
    |   `-- Release
    `-- DLL
        |-- Debug
        `-- Release
```

I would like to have it that I just have to hit `build solution` and the library files from my `DLL` are automatically copied to `SolutionDir/.libs/DLL/*` (* = `include` && `lib` && `bin`). And the `(DLL).dll` file should also be copied to the `SolutionDir/.build/Executable/(Configuration)`.

I imagine I could create a `batch`file to copy the files, but how do I run it each time the `DLL` is built?
Or is there some built-in functionality of MSVC that can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Post-Build Event"; In Command Line, add `copy /Y "$(TargetPath)" "$SolutionDir/.libs/DLL/lib"` and others.

Comment: So how exactly does the command work? `copy /Y "(TargetPath)" "SourcePath"`. And what does `/Y`mean?

Comment: copy is a windows/dos command. /Y to suppress confirmation. $(TargetPath) refers to target of your project, ie. the DLL.